# Godaddy fails to make connection with remote server via curl

Tags: php, curl, server

Ok, I am having a hard time simply trying to get contents from Go Daddy Host server to our company's proprietary server.  Originally I was using file_get_contents, then I searched all over SO and realized curl was a better option to bypass security and configuration.  Here is my code:

```
function get_content($URL){
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;
}

echo 'curl:' . get_content('https://xxx-xxxxx:4032/test2.html');
```

Here is the error:

> Curl error: Failed to connect to xxx-xxxxx.com port 4032: Connection refused

Here are some facts:

- If I enter the URL into my browser, I will be able to retreive test2.html
- If execute the EXACT script on a different web host (Lunar Pages), then it will work perfectly fine
- get_content() will work on google.com
- Go Daddy representatives cannot help us
- On our server, we've disabled the firewall (while we tested this)

Comment: `connection refused` - either there's a firewall on either end actively blocking requests, or there's nothing at that host:port combo listening.

Comment: Why not contact godaddy support? If it works on google, it should do the same for other websites.

Comment: @Xorifelse We called several times.  Look at the fourth bullet under facts, this implies we've tried that.  Or else I would not make such a definitive statement.

Comment: GoDaddy blocks just about everything outbound. If you only need to do this one time, I'd just temporarily change your local server to listen on the standard port 443 instead of 4032, and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

I would have posted this with a comment, but I don't have enough upvotes to do that. GoDaddy is one of the worst hosts for custom code. Sure they're good for things like WordPress, but if you're wanting custom functionality within your code, they're one of the worst.

This is just an example, GoDaddy blocks most file_get_contents and cURL calls within their firewall. I would go with a host like HostGator or Digital Ocean... Both are cheap but not near as limiting.

Before making a switch, I would try to run this same code on another environment locally and make sure you can connect.

Comment: You're claim could be right but I need solid evidence for me to be completely convinced.  Remember, I can do file_get_contents on google.com and other websites.  In fact, one of our server is outside the AT&T firewall and it can even reach that, so it's not just really popular sites that it allows.  We called one of our AT&T rep and had him listen in on the network, it turns out none of our scripts ever hit the firewall.  So you may be right, but again, I would like to see incriminating evidence.

Comment: Try getting a HostGator account, using the coupon code "DarKnight" will give you an account for a penny to test with, run your code there and see if it works.